# Prove that lim sup $a_n$ $\leq$ lim sup $b_n$.

Tags: analysis

Let $a_n$, $b_n$ be bounded sequences of real numbers and suppose that there exists N so that $a_n$ $\leq$ $b_n$ for all n $\geq$ N. Prove that lim sup $a_n$ $\leq$ lim sup $b_n$.

I can see why this would be true.

We are given that $a_n$ $\leq$ $b_n$.  Since sup $a_n$ is just another term in our sequence $a_n$ and sup $b_n$ is just another $b_n$, then sup $a_n$ $\leq$ sup $b_n$.

I also understand that sup $a_n$ is not only an upper bound, but the least upper bound of ($a_n$).  So $a_n$ $\leq$ sup $a_n$.  Similarly, $b_n$ $\leq$ sup $b_n$.

Altogether, we have $a_n$ $\leq$ sup $a_n$ $\leq$ $b_n$ $\leq$ sup $b_n$.

Clearly, sup $a_n$ $\leq$ sup $b_n$.

But I don't know how to show that lim sup $a_n$ $\leq$ lim sup $b_n$.

I know lim sup $a_n$ is the same thing as sup $a_n$ converging to a point, let's call it $a$.  So, lim sup $a_n$ means if we let $\epsilon$ > 0, then there exists N such that |sup $a_n$ - $a$| < $\epsilon$ whenever $n$ >N.

Another definition of the lim sup that may be more helpful is: Let E be the set of all subsequential limits of a bounded sequence ($a_n$), then lim sup $a_n$ = sup E.  So the lim sup is the least upper bound of all the limits that the subsequences converge to.

We also have that our sequences ($a_n$) and (bn) are bounded which means that there exists M>0 such that |$a_n$| $\leq$ M for all n in N.  Similaryly, there exists L>0 such that |$b_n$| $\leq$ L for all $n$ in N.

Since we're given that these sequences are bounded we should be using that in our proof.

So, I basically have all these tools - bounded sequences, convergence, etc- but I'm not sure how that all proves that lim sup $a_n$ $\leq$ lim sup $b_n$.

Answer (score 2):

You just go to the definition of $\limsup$. We define $A_n = \sup_{m\geq n} a_m$ and $B_n = \sup_{m\geq n}b_m$. Since $a_n \leq b_n$, $A_n \leq B_n$ for every $n>N$. Then, $\inf A_n \leq A_n \leq \inf B_n \leq B_n$, but $\inf A_n = \limsup a_n$ and $\inf B_n = \limsup b_n$.

Comment: How do we know that the inf $A_n$ = lim sum $a_n$?

Comment: It's the definition. $\sup_{m\geq n} a_n$ is a non-increasing sequence (why?), and it is bounded (because the sequence is bounded). Therefore, it converges (to the inf).

Comment: I don't understand what $A_n$ is, is $A_n$ the sup of subsequences of $a_n$?

Comment: $A_n$ is the sup of the terms of $a_n$. For example, $A_1 = \sup\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k,\ldots\}$, $A_2 = \sup\{a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_k,\ldots\}$ and $A_n = \sup\{a_n,a_{n+1},\ldots\}$. Note that $A_1 \geq A_2 \geq \ldots \geq A_n \geq \ldots$ (why?), therefore, this sequence is non-increasing. And it is limited, because $a_n$ is limited.

Comment: So the inf(sup $a_n$) = lim sup $a_n$?

Comment: Yes! Here is a link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior. I think it might make things easier.

Comment: Is $A_1$ $\geq$ $A_1=2$ $\geq$ ... $\geq$ $A_n$ $\geq$... because the sequence $a_n$ is bounded?

Comment: No. It's because $A_2 \subset A_1$, therefore, $\sup A_1 \geq \sup A_2$.

Comment: Oh right, right! I'm still a little confused as to why inf(sup $a_n$), but I'll try looking at your link.